# How to fire jQuery event when all shipping methods are loaded in Magento2 checkout page?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, onepage-checkout, knockoutjs

I want to fire some jQuery event when all shipping methods are completely loaded on checkout page. Which function of which file is to be used? please help.